# Acessar texto de botão

Tags: ios, swift

Galera boa tarde...
Estou com o seguinte, preciso saber o titulo que esta em um botão , como se fosse .text , para definir uso  o setTitle , mas e para saber qual o nome ?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você acessar o título do botão você tem de acessar primeiro o `UILabel`, pois o título do botão é um `UILabel`.

Para acessar faz da seguinte forma:

```
button.titleLabel!.text
```

Comment: No log e;e aparece OPtionall ("texto") para uma eventual comparação com if não é necessario por este optional ne ? ou seja posso fazer if(labelDoBt == "meu titulo do botao ") ?

Comment: Isso, esse "Optional" apenas diz que o valor é opcional

Comment: saquei obrigado....